# Hosting Multiple Web Pages in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

I have created frontend of my app using reactjs. It has three components Home, Signin and Signup. After building frontend using `npm run build` I have created backend using nodejs. In backend I have used `app.use(express.statis(path_to_build_directory_in_reactjs))`. When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:9000/` it shows home page. But when I goto `http://127.0.0.1:9000/signin` page it says `can not get /signin`. Before building reactjs, it was showing signin page but after adding backend, it only shows home page.

**Nodejs**

```
onst express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build')))
app.use(express.json());




app.post('/timeline',(req,res)=>
{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end();
})





app.listen(9000,()=>
{
    console.log(9000);
})
```

**Reactjs**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './pages/Home.js';
import Signin from './pages/Signin.js';
import Signup from './pages/Signup.js';
import Help from './pages/Help';
import Timeline from './pages/Timeline.js';



function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/signin">
            <Signin />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/signup">
            <Signup />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/help">
            <Help />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/timeline">
            <Timeline />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: try to add ` app.all("*", (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });`

Comment: @Sodhisaab it says `handle()` is not defined.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The React development server supports multiple routes by default. The browser can ask for `/signin` and the React development server will serve up the react application at that URL.

The statically built site you are generating **only** has an `index.html` so only the one route is supported as an entry point to the application.

If you request `/signin` from Express then it will 404 because there is no such directory.

---

The quick and dirty hack to get this to work is to create a route which serves up `index.html` for **each** of the routes in the client-side React code (you might be able to get away with using a `*` route **after** all  your other routes, although that would break all 404 errors)

This then depends on client-side rendering to adjust the view to match the route.

---

The *better* approach is to use server-side rendering via a tool such as [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) which will generate the appropriate HTML for a view **on the server** before handing over to client-side rendering for subsequent requests if it is supported on the client.

---

If you were dealing with only static content (since you have a `/signin` route, you probably **aren't**) then you could look to a tool like [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) which will generate static pages for each route.